# Android layout design for mobile and tablet with Vector drawable as background

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, svg, layout

Can someone suggest me a best method for designing android layout to support mobile devices as well as tablet.
The have attached the screenshots of 3 different device( 2 tablet and one mobile)

[image]

I have used layout-sw600dp to support al tablets. I hope all layout under this will load for tablets with min width of 600dp (ie the smallest side)

> question : Is this the right way to separate layouts for mobile and tablets?

One issue I faced is the vector xml file get stretched when it comes to tablet(I have attached the vector xml code below)

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt"
  android:width="360dp"
  android:height="640dp"
  android:viewportWidth="360"
  android:viewportHeight="640">
<path
    android:pathData="M0,0h360v640h-360z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"/>
<path
    android:pathData="M0.001,0h360v10.634l-360,207.846Z">
  <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
    <gradient 
        android:startY="6.1174397"
        android:startX="309.601"
        android:endY="58.989597"
        android:endX="-134.99901"
        android:type="linear">
      <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FFFFB88C"/>
      <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FFDE6262"/>
    </gradient>
  </aapt:attr>
</path>
<path
    android:pathData="M70.674,0L360,0L360,501.127Z">
  <aapt:attr name="android:fillColor">
    <gradient 
        android:startY="-30.568748"
        android:startX="197.39879"
        android:endY="501.127"
        android:endX="387.7753"
        android:type="linear">
      <item android:offset="0" android:color="#FFDE6262"/>
      <item android:offset="1" android:color="#FFFFB88C"/>
    </gradient>
  </aapt:attr>
</path>
```

What is the right way for adding vector xml files of svg images. Do I need multiple version of this xml file( If so what is the naming convention to match different screen sized)
I think I have made this before but cause duplicate xml error (ie when I add it to drawable-ldpi, xhdpi etc)

Can someone suggest me a best solution for android layout on the above case

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use SDP library here's the link https://github.com/intuit/sdp you don't have to worry about creating different layouts for different screen sizes it will fit itself.

Comment: What about vector xml files that get stretched?

Comment: I tried sdp but doesnt work as expected, for example text field with full width looks good on mobile but looks bad on large screen .. ie for a login page with email and password